# How do I extract data from an XMLTYPE field by attribute?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

Forgive me for being a total beginner.

I am looking at a column named `FORM_XML` that is described as data type `XMLTYPE`.
The contents of **one** field is:

```
<Form FormID="0" Name="Preventive Care(F)">
  <FormObject Name="prevcare01" Type="DateTime" Label="Physical Exam" EditValue="04/05/2007" />
  <FormObject Name="prevcare02" Type="DateTime" Label="Lipid Profile" EditValue="NoEditValue" />
  <FormObject Name="prevcare03" Type="DateTime" Label="Health Care Proxy review" EditValue="NoEditValue" />
  <FormObject Name="prevcarecomm" Type="Text" Label="Comments" EditValue="NoEditValue" />
</Form>
```

The goal is to extract the `EditValue` date where `Label="Physical exam"`. In this example, the date `04/05/2007` is what I want to extract. Is there a magic query that can accomplish this?

Existing questions haven't helped because their XML data is structured differently. Is my XML data structured wrong because it doesn't contain namespaces, and specific labels?

FOLLOW-UP QUESTION:
I ran

```
SELECT Extract(form_xml, '/Form/FormObject/@EditValue') FROM patient_form;
```

And got the `EditValue` for all `FormObjects` concatenated together. Is it possible to filter out just the `EditValue` where `Label="Physical exam"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XMLTABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm#SQLRF06232) to convert XML to rows and columns and then apply your filter.

Query:

```
SQL> with x(y) as (
  select xmltype('<Form FormID="0" Name="Preventive Care(F)">
  <FormObject Name="prevcare01" Type="DateTime" Label="Physical Exam" EditValue="04/05/2007" />
  <FormObject Name="prevcare02" Type="DateTime" Label="Lipid Profile" EditValue="NoEditValue" />
  <FormObject Name="prevcare03" Type="DateTime" Label="Health Care Proxy review" EditValue="NoEditValue" />
  <FormObject Name="prevcarecomm" Type="Text" Label="Comments" EditValue="NoEditValue" />
</Form>') from dual
  )
select z.*
from x cross join
xmltable('Form/FormObject' passing x.y
         columns label_ varchar2(30) path '@Label',
                 editvalue_ varchar2(30) path '@EditValue'
         ) z
where z.label_ = 'Physical Exam';
```

Result:

```
LABEL_                         EDITVALUE_
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Physical Exam                  04/05/2007
```

Or use XQuery to filter it before converting to rows and columns.

Query:

```
SQL> with x(y) as (
  select xmltype('<Form FormID="0" Name="Preventive Care(F)">
  <FormObject Name="prevcare01" Type="DateTime" Label="Physical Exam" EditValue="04/05/2007" />
  <FormObject Name="prevcare02" Type="DateTime" Label="Lipid Profile" EditValue="NoEditValue" />
  <FormObject Name="prevcare03" Type="DateTime" Label="Health Care Proxy review" EditValue="NoEditValue" />
  <FormObject Name="prevcarecomm" Type="Text" Label="Comments" EditValue="NoEditValue" />
</Form>') from dual
  )
select z.*
from x cross join
xmltable('for $i in /Form/FormObject
                where $i/@Label = "Physical Exam"
                return $i' passing x.y
         columns label_ varchar2(30) path '@Label',
                 editvalue_ varchar2(30) path '@EditValue'
         ) z;
```

Result:

```
LABEL_                         EDITVALUE_
------------------------------ ------------------------------
Physical Exam                  04/05/2007
```

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are usually what makes life complicated, no namespace should be simpler.

```
/Form/FormObject/@EditValue
```

Comment: Hey, I have a follow-up question and could use some help. Any suggestions?